# owner field value disappears when coping document to another SC

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfield

On RootWeb of both site collections I have created same User field (owner). I mean same user field becuase I used same ID (GUID), name and everything. Then I add the field to a content Type and add the content type to all Document libraries for both site collections. But still when I copy a document from a document library in a Site collection to another Document library within another site collection the value of owner field disappears. thanks for all advice.

Comment: How do you copy the document? It'll be almost impossible to keep the IDs of users in two site collections in sync as thats the ID of the user in the User Information List and depends on the order the users visit/are used in the site

Comment: I use open libraries in explorer view and copy paste the document. the question is why the value of "Edited by" is copied while both fields are User type.

Answer (score 1):

if you do it programmatically you could refer to the hidden list located at _catalog/users/detail.aspx and try to find the User by it's name there and set it to the right id for the other site collection